# Get full details of displayed tasks on same page in laravel 6

Tags: html, laravel

I have displayed posted tasks after fetching them from database in `laravel 6`. All i want is that by clicking on one of the tasks i should get its details on the same page in another `div` to proceed further. But it's not giving me anything.

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is the code]

---

it is tack.blade file which is showing all tasks